# CLR is optimising my forloop variables away

Tags: c#, variables, loops, for-loop, clr

I'm trying to run a basic loop that will find a specific value in a dataview grid. I cannot figure out whats going on with the code, since the for loop exits before evaluating its basic condition.

```
private void SearchDataViewGrid(string FileName)
    {
        //finds the selected entry in the DVG based on the image
            for (int i = 0; i == dataPartsList.Rows.Count ; i++)
            {
                if(FileName == dataPartsList.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString())
                {
                dataPartsList.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

The program doesn't crash, but i get an error on my 'i' variables declaring that it has been optimised away. Tried a few easy fixes i found online but nothing seems to keep it.

I have verified that the string i am passing is the correct one, and my 'dummy' DVG returns a value of 14 for the number of rows contained. Even if i remove the 'if' statement inside of the for loop, i still get the same error.

Comment: Change it to `for (int i = 0; i < dataPartsList.Rows.Count ; i++)`

Comment: @Henk: You should turn that into an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The condition `cond` in the middle of `for(init; cond; update)` is not an *until* condition but a *while* condition.

So you need to change it to

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataPartsList.Rows.Count ; i++)
```

Comment: bah...been here for too long....i was evaluating a freaking true statment, no wonder it wasn't firing....thanx for the help guys, i actually just changed the == into != and its working properly now.

Comment: Any reason not to follow the common practice and use the more informative `<` ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your conditional is `i == dataPartsList.Rows.Count` so the body will only execute when these two values are equal.  This guarantees your loop will never execute.  You need to change your conditional to be `<` instead of `==`

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataPartsList.Rows.Count ; i++) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Ed, Davide, working on 4 hours of sleep.  Thansk for the catch!